# How can I get revert the changes of git pull?

Tags: git, version-control

I had taken VCS pull from Git but aborted the process. There after I messed up with my codes as the stash saved unncessary comments. To skip with the stash comments, I reverted the version. Now I lost some of the codes that I had changed.

Is there a way I can restore my local changes before taking that pull from VCS?

I'm new to Git and really don't have time to go through all the documents and stuff to read the whole process.

Comment: tip. always commit before taking pull or push.

Comment: question does not relate to Android and Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't commit your changes before pulling external changes then I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

your check your local history, there also a copy of changes present[image]
right click on Project -> local history ->Show History -> then a panel will appear then your can figure out what changes your have made. just copy and pasted it then.

Comment: if he is not committing changes and not even using IDE the i believe its not possible!

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Comment: please accept the answer on clicking right icon so that it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

I got the annotation from the changes that were stashed even after abort action. Thus unstashing the changes solved this problem. 
Android Studio option on toolbar:

> > VCS >> Git >> UnStach Changes...